# Integrity contraint violation when trying to call save multiple times

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

Consider the following classes:

```
@Entity
public class MyDomain{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private AnotherDomain anotherDomain;

    //getters and setters here
}
```

---

```
@Repository
public MyDomainDao extends DaoBase<MyDomain>{

    public List<MyDomain> doSomething(AnotherDomain parameter){
        //code does something here
    }

}
```

---

```
public class DaoBase<I>{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void save(I object){
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(object);
    }
}
```

---

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:context.xml"})
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
public class MyDomainDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyDomainDao dao;    

    @Mock
    private AnotherDomain anotherDomain;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.setupListOfMyDomain();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoSomething(){
        //test the method here
    }

    private void setupListOfMyDomain(){
        MyDomain domain = null;     

        //five rows of MyDomain
        for(int i=0; i<=4; i++){
            domain = new MyDomain();
            domain.setAnotherDomain(anotherDomain);
            dao.save(domain);
        }       
    }
}
```

To summarize, I have a simple entity class (`MyDomain`) and a domain dao (`MyDomainDao`) that extends from the super class `DaoBase`.  It is in this super class where the session for the persistence is called and it is also the responsibility of this super class to save/update/delete the entity class.  By virtue of inheritance, subclasses only has to define child-specific methods.

The problem begins when I run the unit/integration test `MyDomainDaoTest`.  I wanted to test that the method `doSomething()` defined in `MyDomainDao`.  In order to do that, I need to five test rows in the database (I am using HSQLDB in-memory), thus the loop in the method `setupListOfMyDomain()`.  What is strange about the loop is that I get this error on the second iteration:

```
ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter - integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_CT_10231 table: MyDomain
```

It cannot get any cryptic than that.  I know that an ID is generated on the first iteration. Why am I getting an integrity constraint violation for the succeeding iteration if I am trying to persist another object?

Comment: SYS_CT_10231 is the name of the constraint.  Go look for it in your DB with whatever DB tool you use.

Comment: I'd probably do that but I'm using an HSQLDB in-memory (meaning the database is not generated as a flat/system file).  I'm not particularly sure if I can even get the metadata of the generated table at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem in your mapping. Your are declaring a one-to-one relation between `MyDomain` and `AnotherDomain` but in your unit test the 5 instances of `MyDomain` share the same instance of `AnotherDomain` so you should use a many-to-one relation instead.

Comment: Bingo~! I changed the annotation from `@OneToOne` to `@ManyToOne` and the setup went through. I never got to use `@ManyToOne` before. Now I have. Thanks~!